# Adding a zip file to Nexus

Tags: maven, jenkins, deployment, nexus

For some reason I'm struggling wih the following and looking at all the examples on the web are not helping with my use case. I'm at the end of a very complex and odd build cycle with delivers a zip file to my desktop which contains a number of components.
I don't have any control on the creation of the zip file.
I'd like to upload this zip file into Nexus, partly for storage and for release control.
I'm trying to use mvn deploy:deploy-file but when i try to use 
zip in my pom file I get the following error :

```
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: zip @ line 6, column 13
```

A lot of the example suggest using
pom within the pom file, which doesn't error but doesn't upload the zip file.

Command Line I'm using is :

```
D:\tmp3>mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots 
-DrepositoryId=snapshots
-Dfile=d:\tmp3\test.zip
-DpomFile=pom.xml
```

Pom file is as simple as I could make it :

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>testzip</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>zip</packaging>
</project>
```

If I ignore using a pom file and specify the groupID etc as part of the commandline it works.

```
D:\tmp3>mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots -DrepositoryId=snapshots -Dfile=d:\tmp3\test.zip
-DgroupId=com.test.app -DartifactId=testzip -Dversion=1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

If I remove the packaging tag from the pom, it works, but uploads the zip as a jar !

Eventually I'll need to bubble this up into Jenkins, but for now I'll be happy to get it to work from the command line.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Zip files are often deployed as jar into the Nexus. `Javadoc` and `Sources` are not really jars as well, but handled as such. Technically, a jar is a zip file anyway.

You can try to deploy it with `-Dpackaging=zip` over the command line or you just deploy it as jar.

Comment: As per the first lines of the port, If i try packaging=zip in he pom it fails with the error, However it does work from the command line.